# How do the magical girls match up to their prefecture?

Tags: mahou-shoujo-taisen

In Magica Wars (Mahō Shōjo Taisen) There are 47 Magical girls, one for each prefecture.

The designs for the magical girls were decided on Pivix during a competition, and there is an iOS game of the same title, so the list of the girls should be out there somewhere.

What I was wondering was how do the girls match up to the prefectures, as it will be hard to keep track of later on as more characters are introduced.

I already know (from the anime) of:

- Miyagi Prefecture: **Naruko Aoba**
- Shizuoka Prefecture: **Matsuri Sengen**
- Tokyo Prefecture: **Rin Kobari**
- Ishikawa Prefecture: **Yuri Inuwashi**
- Mie-ken: **Suzuka Kamiki**
- Kumamoto Prefecture: **Renka Ariake**
- Kyoto Prefecture: **Mebuki Konoe**

Comment: (About the tag), in this case, I really prefer the Japanese tag, since it is less confusing: Magica Wars (Mahou Shoujo Taisen) vs. Magical Warfare (Mahou Sensou).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Magica Wars Wikia](http://magica-wars.wikia.com/wiki/Characters) has updated with a list of the girls.

The series only included a few of them, here are the prefecture's girls in their entirety (with pictures where available)

**Aichi:** Rin Takehara & Subaru Amashita

[image]

**Akita:** Mai Inakura & Topiko Arube

**Aomori:** Neo Shiratori & Rui Shirakawagoshi

**Chiba:** Sen Hazakura

[image]

**Ehime:** Setoka Himeno

[image]

**Fukui:** Fuku Echizen

[image]

**Fukuoka:** Arisu Sugawara & Ume Hoshino

N/A , [image]

[image]

**Fukushima:** Momo Iwaki

[image]

**Gifu:** Hidari & Minori Ichiki, Shizuri Tsuzuku

[image] , N/A

**Gunma:** Tsutsuji Makai

[image]

**Hiroshima:** Akane Wajima & Miwa Kyuumon

[image] , [image]

**Hokkaido:** Komako Kitano & Yuki Miku

[image] , [image]

**Hyogo:**  Hotaru Kugui & Tamae Sakamoto

N/A , [image]

**Ibaraki:** Mio Kasama &  Nobara Yuuki

N/A , [image]

**Ishikawa:** Yuri Inuwashi

[image]

**Iwate:**  Meguru Hoshi &  Yuki

[image] , [image]

**Kagawa:** Kanoka Tamamo

[image]

**Kagoshima:**  Hayame Kaji

[image]

**Kanagawa:** Minamo Kousaka

[image]

**Kochi:** Monobe Tsurugi

**Kumamoto:** Renka Ariake

[image]

**Kyoto:** Mebuki Konoe & Miyako Saionji

[image] , N/A

**Mie:** Suzuka Kamiki

[image]

**Miyagi:** Naruko Aoba

[image]

**Miyazaki:**   Himuka Amano

[image]

**Nagano:** Shinanono Kawanakajima

[image]

**Nagasaki:** Ameko Kamishiro

[image]

**Nara:** Fuhiko Fujiwara

[image]

**Niigata:** Ichiko Echigo

[image]

**Oita:** Kemuri Midoriyu & Touka Taketori

[image] , N/A

**Okayama:** Suzume Momomura

[image]

**Okinawa:** Manami Hika & Menou Amakusa

[image] , N/A

**Osaka:** Sakura Midou & Yana Minase

[image] , N/A

**Saga:** Sayaka Yoshino

[image]

**Saitama:** Tamame Saijou

N/A

**Shiga:** Kinoe Oumi

[image]

**Shimane:** Chitose Kunibiki

[image]

**Shizuoka:** Matsuri Sengen

[image]

**Tochigi:** Hikari Tochinobi

[image]

**Tokushima:**  Narumi Sudachi  Hi-san & Sara Shirasagi

N/A , [image]

**Tokyo:**  Rin Kobari

[image]

**Tottori:** Chiyo Miasa

N/A

**Toyama:** Karin Hotarui

[image]

**Wakayama:** Kino Shirarahama

[image]

**Yamagata:** Yukana Akaba

[image]

**Yamaguchi:** Natsumi Manten

[image]

**Yamanashi:** Koi Momoyama

[image]

If anyone can fill in the blanks, that'd be great. If you speak Japanese, there's a [card site here](http://orenoturn.org/?mode=grp&gid=933923)